# "jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted" in getPrice function

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, rpc, ether

make 1NFT free -> after nft per .0022  sale function

so I made this get price function,

```
function getPrice(address _sender,uint256 _quantity) public view returns (uint256){
    uint256 _userFreeAmount = maxFree.sub(_numberMinted(_sender)); //can free 
    if (_userFreeAmount<=0){ 
        return price.mul(_quantity);//error
    }else if(_quantity.sub(_userFreeAmount)<=0){
         return 0;
    }else{
        return price.mul(_quantity.sub(_userFreeAmount));
    }
}
```

and it make rpc error in
this case -> "if (_userFreeAmount<=0)"

and my mint function on front is this

```
const mint = async () => {
    let myProvider = web3.currentProvider;
    let networkCheck = myProvider.networkVersion == null ? myProvider.chainId : myProvider.networkVersion;
    if (networkCheck == CHAINID) {
        if (contract && account) {
            const quantity = parseInt($('.supply').text());
            try {
                const price = await contract.methods.getPrice(account,quantity).call();
                await contract.methods.publicMint(quantity).send({ from: account, value: price});
                $.statusSection.init("minting success.");
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.name);
                alert(error.message)
            }
        }
    } else {
        await switchNetwork();
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: Anh console.log the quantity variable, maybe it cause error because it is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

At

```
uint256 _userFreeAmount = maxFree.sub(_numberMinted(_sender));
```

It is possible that result would be negative number. `uint256` is not used for negative number, thats why rpc reverts when underflow happen. You can use `int256` instead.

> Arithmetic operations revert on underflow and overflow. You can use
> unchecked { ... } to use the previous wrapping behaviour.

See [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/080-breaking-changes.html#silent-changes-of-the-semantics)